# REST API to get the status of Azure DevOps service Connection

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

After updating the service connection(with change in service principle Key) using a `PUT` method, I want to verify the service connection status using `REST API`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

[image]

I tried to use the `isReady` flag what we GET in service endpoint json response, however it does not reflect though I update the service connection with wrong SPN key.

```
 "isReady":true,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my test, this [Update Service Connection Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)  will not verify whether the connection is successful.

It will directly update the service connection(save without verification).

For authentication of this service connection:

You need to run another Rest API to verify it: [Endpointproxy - Execute Service Endpoint Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpointproxy/execute%20service%20endpoint%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

This Rest API is used to verify whether the service connection is successful.

Here is an example:

Rest API:

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/{Project Name}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpointproxy?endpointId={EndpointID}&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{  
 "dataSourceDetails":{"dataSourceName":"TestConnection"}

}
```

Result:

Success

[image]

Fail

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Kevin ! Exactly what I was looking out for.