# Azure DevOps API creates service connection without verifying hence getting the error failed to query service connection api while using

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, serviceconnection

Am able to create a new service endpoint using

[Create Service EndPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

And also able to grant it with Pipeline Permissions using below

curl --request PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u $user:$token -d "@newpatch.json" [https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/pipelines/pipelinePermissions/endpoint/$connection_id\?api-version\=5.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/pipelines/pipelinePermissions/endpoint/$connection_id%5C?api-version%5C=5.1-preview.1)

But when am trying to use the service connection in the pipeline it is giving me below error

Failed to query service connection API: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/resourcegroups?api-version=2019-05-01'. Status Code: 'BadRequest', Response from server: '{"error":{"code":"InvalidSubscriptionId","message":"The provided subscription identifier 'resourcegroups' is malformed or invalid."}}'

I have tried with - [update restproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64427466/rest-api-to-get-the-status-of-azure-devops-service-connection) but I still see the error, not sure on the body for the script

Please help

Comment: Can anyone guide me here ?

Comment: How did you solve this? Getting the same error.

Comment: Hi - This issue occurred when I have passed Service Connection as a variable in terraform task in the yaml

Comment: Providing service connection as a variable at task level is not supported, it should be globally defined or in a variable group

Comment: It has been resolved after updating service connection variable globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing service connection as a variable at terraform task level caused the Issue.

Since it is not supported at task level, it has to be defined globally in the yaml or from variable groups. Issue has been resolved doing it.